# Passing large objects containing data into an interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, strategy-pattern

## Context

I have an abstract class that is using the strategy pattern.

```
public interface IReader
{
    HashSet<DataSheet> Read(string fullFilePath, HashSet<string> sheetNames, ref string errors);
}

public abstract class AbstractReader : IReader
{
    public virtual HashSet<DataSheet> Read(string fullFilePath, Hashset<string> sheetNames, ref string errors)

    protected virtual void InitializeRowColInfo(string filePath, string sheetName)

    //And some other methods
}
```

The method read, reads an excel file and takes in required information through its parameters and outputs information to be further processed.

### Strategy

To implement the Abstract Reader, I create a new class which overwrites the it. For example,

For files that follow the formatting logic of my abstract class,

```
public class ConcreteReader1 : AbstractStandardReader
{
}
```

For files that do not follow the formatting logic of my abstract class,

```
public class ConcreteReader2 : AbstractStandardReader
{
    protected override void InitializeRowColInfo(string filePath, string sheetName)
}
```

where I will override the method according to the formatting needs of the file, while the common methods are reused from the abstract class. And the creation method of objects is as such:

```
public IReader GetReader(string reader){
    if (reader.toUpper().trim().Equals("CONCRETEREADER1"){
        return new ConcreteReader1();
    }
    //Continue else ifs for the other readers
}
```

## Problem: Parameters

However, due to the rigid nature of the parameters that i have included for all methods, whenever a file format that requires additional parameters are needed I cannot reuse my code.

To solve this problem, I can create an object to be passed instead, such as a documentInfo object:

```
public class DocumentInfo
{
    public string FullReadFilePath { get; set; }
    public HashSet<string> SheetNames { get; set; }
    public string Errors { get; set; }
}

public interface IReader
{
    HashSet<DataSheet> Read(DocumentInfo documentInfo);
}
```

This way, any additional parameters that are needed can be added into this object without affecting the existing concrete readers and I can get rid of the ref string.

However,

1. There is an issue of redundancy as any newly added properties to the DocumentInfo object will always be uninitialized and useless for the Readers that do not use them (and also clutter the code).
2. Also, all my other methods will depend on this object as it contains all information regarding reading (fullFilePath, sheetNames, etc.)

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: When you create your special case readers, you can pass parameters in constructor. This way each and every special case reader will have their own set of params, depending on what it does. Would this work?

Comment: That would work, but would it break my strategy pattern?

For example,
`code

    public IReader GetReader(string reader){
    if (reader.toUpper().trim().Equals("CONCRETEREADER1"){
        return new ConcreteReader1(someAdditionalParams);
    }
    //Continue else ifs for the other readers
}

`
I need to supply the params somehow this way when I
`code

    IReader reader = GetReader(ConcreteReader1);

`

Ouch. I really don't know how to put code in comments sorry ...

Comment: Well, your `GetReader` should get more information about the file that it is producing the reader. Now you are getting into Factory pattern. At what point do you know additional parameters that you need to pass in? can you move that point into `ReaderFactory`?

Comment: I pass in the parameters when I call `reader.Read(some params)`, where `reader` is a `IReader`

Answer (score 1):

My understanding, you are trying to do tech refactoring without rethinking objects responsibility (S of SOLID principles https://stackify.com/solid-design-principles/). This leads to trying to combine everything into one class.
I see you could restructure classes in the following way:

1. DocumentInfo - data object describing document structure (this could include RowColInfo if it's part of the strategy)
2. IReader - interface for reading
3. Errors - class for errors (could keep array or create a separate class)
4. InitializeRowColInfo - not sure you need it common, this looks like part of particular reader implementation
5. AbstractReader - do you really need it? rethink of keeping tech methods in a different place/class
6. Get particular reader implementation is outside of the reader scope (keep it the same if you'd like)

To sum up, I would like to use the following structure

```
public class DocumentInfo
{
    public HashSet<string> SheetNames { get; set; }
    // potentially RowColInfo if it's part of your configuration
}

public interface IReader
{
    HashSet<DataSheet> Read(DocumentInfo docuInfo, ref string errors);
}

public class ConcreteReader: IReader
{
    public ConcreteReader(string filePath) {...};
    public HashSet<DataSheet> Read(DocumentInfo docuInfo, ref string errors) {...};
}
```

Actually, that is it.

Comment: Which object does not obey the S in SOLID? I think my Reader has only the responsibility of reading, and DocumentInfo only stores document info. InitializeRowColInfo is a part of my read method of Reader, so that i can freely override it if i need to. Thanks for the help!

Comment: DocumentInfo: why is file path included(it's not part of document structure unless you store one document structure in a file with the definite name)? why are errors (which are part of document processing) included? in my mind, it's not a part of document information. On the other hand, RowColInfo looks like part of information about the document and should be included into DocumentInfo data object.

Comment: After that I'm thinking about AbstractStandardBuildPlanReader and I don't see any reasons why the class should exist (at least I don't see anything in the question description). The same is applied to factory, from the question description I don't see any reasons why it should exist. Something like that. As a result we have a number of classes which look as an overhead and should be excluded from the project to keep library (or module) interface transparent. This is only my vision so you might be seeing it differently.

Comment: Too song answer so I splitted it into 2 pieces.

Comment: Oh, I actually created this DocumentInfo object to contain information such as the path of the document, instead of the contents of the document. As for the Abstract Reader, I changed it to a concrete class instead, due to the overhead as you had pointed out. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Morning. Why do you need DocumentInfo then? What is this class responsibility? Actually, I can't imagine what else you do need to store in this case in addition to the path. Why don't stick to a string instead? In addition to that, there is the generic approach in java and .net to use stream as a source for a file to allow reading from anywhere which doesn't know anything about DocumentInfo class and can't work with it. Think you need to rethink what DocumentInfo responsibility is.

Comment: Hey, Morning. Actually passing in a string was what i did before, but i was facing the problem of having to pass in more parameters for other specific readers, which caused them to be unable to stick to a common `IReader` interface implementation of `Read`. By having a `DocumentInfo` object passed in instead, I can add in additional parameters into the implementation of document info such that those specific readers which needs more info can get them through DocumentInfo. Then I have this problem of whether I should do this because of the redundancy introduced for previous working readers.

Comment: Perhaps another disadvantage of such a solution using DocumentInfo is that it does not follow the SRP as you had mentioned. Thanks for that!

Comment: having to pass in more parameters for other specific readers - looks like to are trying to technically solve the task without thinking of SRP. Try to pass stream object instead of string or document info or whatever to keep reading file content logic separately.

Comment: Approach above is a common thing used in all modern languages